# How basic is this sentence "日本語がわたしはちょっとだけわかります"

Tags: particle-は

Is this sentence so basic or even understandable for Japanese speakers? I am just learning Japanese no prior knowledge about the language. I interchange は/が still. Can I make this even native sounding sentence?

I am trying to say "I only understand a little bit of Japanese" Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give some suggestions, although I am sure there will be a more comprehensive answer

1. You don't really need わたし - it (as well as other 2nd person pronouns) are usually assumed.
2. I am not sure ちょっと　is suitable here, I would use すこし　- a little
3. I don't think だけ is necessary
4. And now that we don't have わたし, I would use は with 日本語

日本語は[少]{すこ}し[分]{わ}かります。

Well, it seems 少しだけ is quite common, so perhaps

日本語は[少]{すこ}しだけ[分]{わ}かります

Comment: Wowww that's a lot different.. I know and I feel like my sentence is so unnatural like a kindergarten Japanese hahaha thanks for this! It gives me more idea on how to construct sentences! 

Comment: +1. ちょっと is a perfectly natural word choice, too. It's just a but more colloquial than 少し.

Comment: @naruto yes, I wasn't sure about that one